# Continuous If statement

Tags: bash, if-statement, timer, timing

I have 2 scripts one is `software.sh` and the other `timer.sh` both get executed in separate terminals. I want the if statement that checks for software execution duration to be checking continuously but apparently it only gets checked once at start of execution :(

This is the `timer.sh` which gets the PID of `software.sh` and counts its running time

```
#!/bin/bash
while ((1)); do
PID_Ardu=$(pidof arducopter)
Time= ps -p $PID_Ardu -oetime= | tr '-' ':' | awk -F: '{ total=0; m=1; } { for (i=0; i < NF; i++) {total += $(NF-i)*m; m *= i >= 2 ? 24 : 60 }} {print total}'
if [[ $Time < 20 ]]; then **#THIS SHOULD BE EXECUTED CONTINOUSLY**
        echo $Time
else 
        echo INSIDE
        ps -ef | grep software| grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
fi
done
```

This is `software.sh` which executes various generated files

```
#!/bin/bash
chmod a+x *.exp


./ACCF01.exp | wait |echo "FINISHED SCRIPT 1" #Run the ACCF01 script

sed -i '/ACCF01.exp/d' ./software.sh #Delete previous line after finishing execution.

./ACCF02.exp | wait |echo "FINISHED SCRIPT 2"

sed -i '/ACCF02.exp/d' ./software.sh

./ACCF03.exp | wait |echo "FINISHED SCRIPT 3"

sed -i '/ACCF03.exp/d' ./software.sh

./ACCF04.exp | wait |echo "FINISHED SCRIPT 4"
```

Comment: Run it with `bash -x timer.sh` or insert `set -x`, it will print the commands it executes.

Comment: No luck :( I've also tried executing the script itself inside the if statement to ensure it gets executed continuously but still....  the if statement only runs at the beginning

Comment: What do you mean with no luck? Post the output so we can analyse it, please.

Comment: BTW: your ps line has no `$(..)` or `\`..\`` around it, is this a bug in the paste or in your script? And there is also no mentioning of software.sh in your script, so its not clear to me how the two scripts are related.

Comment: Hey sorry please check my edited post. regarding ps, I tested it with your suggestions but it outputs the same output, if statement still doesn't work. Can someone run my timer.sh code in their machine with random software PID and see if it responds lol

Comment: The Time= line has still no backticks

Comment: Man thank you so much!!!!!! Can't believe I spent 10 hours for freakin backticks. This goes under life lessons category for sure

Comment: Cool, I crafted it into an answer. I was not expecting it to be the problem, since you wrote the if is executed only once.

Comment: BTW: i think deleting lines in a executing script does not work very reliable. I would not modify the software.sh script directly but for example a directory with symlinks or a textfile with lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Time` variable is assigned a string, not the return value of the pipeline, because it needs to enclose it in `$(..)` or backticks.

In any case the `If` is executed multiple times, it just has no changing numerical value in the variable.

When you try to debug loops and variable assignments you can use `set -x` or start with `bash -x time.sh` in the future. It will print out all lines execute and variables expanded.